# REGEX for Numbers from -999 to 999 , but not -0

Tags: regex

```
^-?[0-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

I have this regex but numbers but it allows `-0`, Any solution?

Comment: it does not allow 0 also , I want 0 but not -0, Thank you

Comment: try `^(?!-0$)-?[0-9][0-9]{0,2}$`

Comment: What about -00, -000, 00 and 000

Comment: Doesn't appear to be right dupe. As `REGEX for Numbers from -999 to 999 , but not -0` is not same as `matching everything but specific pattern`

Comment: Hmm but  `n and -n except -0` is different from `match everything but a specific pattern`. For later case obvious solution would be: `^(?!.*specific).*$` but that won't work with this problem

Comment: For my requirement i just wanted regex that allows 0 , but does not allow -0 and that is working with ^(?!-0$)-?[0-9][0-9]{0,2}$

Comment: `but not -0` part is covered in dupe question but this question is also about matching numbers `-999` to `999`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead assertion to disallow certain match:

```sh
^(?!-0$)-?[0-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bi43Lk/1)

Take note of `(?!-0$)` that says fail the match if we have `-0` and end anchor after matching start anchor `^`.